# Example of noncommutative central reduced rings which is not reduced

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, noncommutative-algebra

A ring $R$ is called central reduced if every nilpotent element is central. Ungor et al. [math.RA 14 Dec 2013](http://arxiv.org/abs/1312.4024v1) has given an example of a commutative ring which is central reduced but not reduced. Can we find an example of a ring which is noncommutative central reduced but not reduced?

Comment: Do you want some kind of non-triviality condition? For example, if $R$ is commutative non-reduced, and $S$ is non-commutative reduced, then $R\times S$ is an example.

Comment: I have deleted my answer; I totally missed the words "not reduced".  Sorry!

Comment: What do you mean by "has given an example"? Is not every commutative ring central reduced by this definition??

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე, I think that you and I misread the poster's question in the same way.  The crucial point, in bold, is that the example is commutative, *and so* central reduced, **but not reduced**.

Comment: @LSpice No no my question was not about the question but about the first sentence. Specifically about the words "has given an example". I mean, if *any* commutative ring is an example...

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე, at the risk of demonstrating that I'm not understanding anyone here:  I think you mean the *second* sentence, right?  If so, then the point is that *not* any commutative ring is an example, only (because Anupam asks for non-reduced but central reduced rings) a commutative ring **that is not reduced**.  Note that this caveat is present already in the second sentence, not just in the main question.

Comment: @LSpice No no I meant the first sentence, and I asked **not** about the content of the question, only about the strange wording in "has given an example of a commutative ring which is central reduced but not reduced". It looks strange for me since any commutative ring is central reduced, and obviously there exist non-reduced commutative rings, so it is trivial that such examples exist. That's all I wanted to say, nothing more.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is yes, and there are many ways to do it.

1. Use Jeremy Rickard's direct product construction.
2. Let $F$ be a field, let $R=F[x\ :\ x^2=0]$, and let $S=R\langle y,z\rangle$ be the extension of $R$ in the noncommuting variables $y,z$.

By the way, I'd personally use "nilpotent-central" to describe this "central reduced" condition, since I think the first phrase is more descriptive of what is happening (we are forcing all nilpotent elements to be central).

Comment: I think the idea behind the name is just that one is replacing the reducedness condition "every nilpotent lies in $\{0\}$" by the similar-looking condition "every nilpotent lies in $Z(R)$."

Comment: @LSpice I didn't communicate what I meant very clearly, so I've modified my answer slightly to more clearly communicate what I meant.